# Jquery 1.4 - select - onchange fired WITHOUT click- Firefox

Tags: jquery, html

I'm seeing really strange behavior - in Firefox, if you have a select dropdown without any item selected, the onchange event fires onblur - even if you're just changing focus to a different element on the page. My select is just a run-of-the-mill select:

```
<select id="mySelect">
        <option value="Value0">Value 0</option>
        <option value="Value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="Value2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

and my js is:

```
$("#mySelect").change(function(){
    alert('Change event fired'); 
});

$("#mySelect").attr('selectedIndex', '-1');
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W8QR4/

Is there any way to prevent the onchange from firing if I **havent** actually clicked a new option (other than upgrading to a newer version of jquery. I know, I'm stuck with it for now)?

**The change event is firing when it SHOULDNT be. I know the code itself actually works.**

Steps to replicate:

1. Click the little down arrow of the select
2. Hover over Value 1 or Value 2 but *do not select it*
3. Click in the **other** input - twice, so focus is removed from the select and passed to the other element

**This only works BEFORE any item is selected in the dropdown. Once a selection is made this doesnt happen**

Comment: Your example works for me pretty fine in firefox!

Comment: I'm on FF on Mac, if that makes a difference?

Comment: May be, not sure but i am trying it on windows :)

Comment: your code work fine for me

Comment: the code works - the problem is that youre **not** supposed to see the "Change event fired" alert when you dont click a new option

Comment: @user1152309 I don't see that here; in FF or Chrome.

Comment: @DadoJerry see my comment above - are you *not* getting the Change event fired alert when you *dont* select a new item?

Comment: @user1152309 No, i am not getting any alert i mean `change()` fired on when _i don't select a new item_ or _focus on other element_

Comment: you are changing the selected index. that would trigger the event. No?

Comment: @Harsh no, without actually clicking on an option... the selected index should not be changing

Comment: Is no one able to replicate this? Is it just something funky happening in my browser?

Comment: @Mooseman it doesnt happen in Chrome - only in FF

Comment: @user1152309 I don't see an alert when I re-select the same option in *either* FF or Chrome. They behave the same.

Comment: @Mooseman dont actually select any option. Just hover over an option and then click in the text input (you have to click in there twice before getting the alert)

Comment: @everyone: can't reproduce in Chrome or FF or even Opera

Comment: @Harsh - it only happens BEFORE any item is selected - you cant reproduce even when you refresh the page and try from scratch?

Comment: Is there any other parto of the code involving #mySelect? Post the full code please so we can see.

Comment: I know, I know. Just saying that the event never triggered in my browsers.
Firefox 22, Chrome 28 and Opera 12.15

Comment: @Harsh - I'm only getting it in Firefox 22. It doesnt happen in Chrome or Opera. I just tried it out on FF Windows and it also happens.

Comment: Btw, this also happens on Firefox 24 (Windows) and jQuery 1.6.1. When you hover some option of a freshly generated select, and then you loose focus of the select by clicking twice anywhere else on the page, it fires the "change" event.

Comment: Still happens with FF 31.6 and jQuery 1.11.2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer I came up with, feel free to comment/improve:

```
$("#mySelect").attr('selectedIndex', '-1');

//Capture the initial selection of each dropdown
$('select').each(function() {
    $(this).data('initialSelection', String($(this).attr('selectedIndex')));
});

//Add click event to all options. When clicked, change initial selection and unbind the click event
$('select option').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().data('initialSelection', '').attr('selectedIndex', this.index).find('option').unbind('click');
});

//Onchange, check if initial selection is still -1. (If there is a click it will be reset to '') 
//Otherwise, it was just a hover - reset selected index to -1
$('select').change(function(e){
    if($(this).data('initialSelection') == '-1'){
         $(this).attr('selectedIndex', '-1');
    }
});
```

Comment: just remember the last option in the global scope and check if last and selected option are the same, sounds easier.

Comment: @joelharkes thanks for the comment - but i have multiple selects to do this to, and not all have unique ID's

Comment: ok, then i would remember the value of the selected option in the select data