# Firefox selectedIndex on select changes on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, html-select

In Firefox, there seems to be some weird issues around when the `selectedIndex` of a `select` field changes. It seems to change on hover, rather than on click.

Using:

```
setInterval(function(){console.log($('select').prop('selectedIndex'));}, 1000);
```

I can see the `selectedIndex` change as I **hover** over different items (the items getting a blue background and white text as I hover over them).

In Chrome, the `selectedIndex` only changes when an option is clicked.

I can't think of a way to work around this - I've tried to capture clicks on the options and check those against a data attribute on the select as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403991/jquery-1-4-select-onchange-fired-without-click-firefox) but the click handler only seems to work sporadically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when i try this on my page:

```
  $('select[name=sel1]').change(function(){
      alert(this.value);
  });
```

With this select:

```
<select name="sel1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Than in firefox it only alerts when i select the option...

Greetings

Comment: Thanks for this - seems to be an issue with a plugin I'm using. Going to investigate why the 'plugin' select is changing on hover...

Comment: It's true that the change event is triggered only when another option is selected. But the question is about hovering on another option without actually clicking it. In this case FF changes selectedIndex. It's weird! FF bug?